# Dual Zone forced air system not working correctly when both zones are active

Tags: hvac

Sometimes both dampers remain (or become) closed when the thermostat calls for one of them to open and the other one to close.

The zone board is Honeywell Mini-Zone.

Comment: What make and model is your zone board?